# Interesting exemplary cases where natural/political boundaries have led to language divergence

Tags: language-change, list-of-languages, sociolinguistics, dialects

I'm looking for nice examples of the influence of natural or political boundaries to dialect divergence for introductory purposes. Generally through some limitations on the ability of people to interact. I know there are many out there, but it would be nice if it was one that has been well described and illustratable with an image. Maybe Swiss dialect diversity or Rhineland vowel shift pockets?

Comment: There is really no reason to close this question. A question for nice examples of a linguistic phenomenon is always on topic.

Comment: What part makes a difference interesting for you? Geographical features leading to dialect/language difference are most of everything. British vs American English? Sicilian vs Calabrian? Lots of maps showing the difference between the American Southern accent and the more Northern. Do you really just want political boundaries?

Comment: There are phonetic differences in the dialect of North Saami spoken in Guovdageaidnu correlated with Norway / Finland. The cause though is not the border or a geographical feature, it's the fact that the countries have different national languages, so speakers in Norway also speak Norwegian and speakers in Finland also speak Finnish – the cause is different L2s, not political boundary. You mean like that?

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer! Yes, these are exactly the kind of answers I am interested in. Sorry, that "interesting" was a bit vague. I was interested in cases where obstacles to interaction could be seen in the way languages have developed. What would make it interesting, if it could be tied to a story, for example part of a community moving to live to another island or beyond a mountain-range - with a nice map representation. Indeed the Norway-Finland boundary is very interesting to know for future ref. Currently I'm looking for something more target-neutral (no contact influence).

Comment: The Alps are a good natural boundary, each valley has it own dialect.  [Ladin dialects](http://www.ladinia.it/en/informations/394/ladinia/the-ladin-language) follow the Dolomite valleys, [Alemannic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alemannic_German) on a larger scale follows many natural boundaries.

Comment: Thanks! That's an excellent case indeed and I was also looking for materials on them as I've precisely heard about this on Swiss valleys. Can you think of any visual illustration, that nicely shows both natural and dialect boundaries/features on one map or side-by-side. Thanks a lot for the help!

Comment: I would line it up with this map, or a similar one https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/f/fc/Reliefkarte_Schweiz3.png/1280px-Reliefkarte_Schweiz3.png

Maybe insert both into GIMP and set the language map to 50% transparent and crop it so it shows mainly Switzerland.

Comment: This map shows inhabited towns in Switzerland, and gives a good impression of how isolated some valleys are.

http://blog.tagesanzeiger.ch/datenblog/wp-content/uploads/sites/32/2014/06/Mietpreise-Schweiz1.jpg

Comment: Thanks a lot, good advice, and the inhabitation map is great!

Answer (score 4):

I understand that [Korean](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/North%E2%80%93South_differences_in_the_Korean_language) is the prime example of this. South Korean is more open to loanwords, particularly from English, while North Korean was subject to changes stemming from the Juche ideology.

Answer (score 3):

In the 1920s, the Japanese linguist Hattori Shirō wanted to investigate local dialects.  At the time, the two most notorious dialectal areas in the region were Tokyo-style or "Eastern", and Kyoto-style or "Western" Japanese.  The two areas differ in vocabulary: For example, the copula "to be" in Tokyo is *da*, while Kyoto prefers *ya*. They differ in grammar: for example, to conjugate the verb *taberu*, "to eat", into the negative, "not eat", Tokyo goes *tabe-nai* while Kyoto uses *tabe-hen*.  And they differ in pitch accent patterns; in Tokyo *HAshi* means "chopsticks" and *haSHI* means "bridge", while in Kyoto it's the other way around.  But Hattori wanted to map out precise borders, so he took the train, and stopped at every stop to talk to people and listen.

Turns out that *exactly up to the east margin* of the Ibi river in Mie one finds Tokyo-style pitch.  Cross the river and people on the other side clearly talk in Kyoto pitch.

[image]

This was surprising to everyone because people to the east of Ibi (in Gifu and Aichi) used Kyoto-style *grammar and vocab*; before Hattori's research, people thought they spoke "Western (Kyoto-style) Japanese".  To put it another way, if you come from Tokyo you'll find a mixed "buffer zone" east of Ibi where the pitch is still Eastern (Tokyo) style, but word choice and inflections are already Western-style.

Hattori explained this as follows.  In modern times Tokyo is the prestige, standard dialect, and it's easy to find Kyoto natives who adopt Tokyo-style words and grammar; however, they hardly ever manage to change their pitch accent.  (One reason is that the "accent classes", i.e. the groups of words with the same melody, do not match between dialects; so that you can't predict how will the pitch change in the other dialect).  To put it simply, pitch is more resistant to the standard. It's easy to imitate the rules of the prestige grammar, or to borrow the words of the standard lexicon; but it's hard to change the tones of every single word.

And it so happens that, for most of Japanese history, the standard dialect was Kyoto, not Tokyo (i.e. the opposite of today).  The fact that the Kyoto pitch falls neatly along the Ibi river must show that it spread up to this natural/cultural barrier, and stopped.  The fact that the people east of the river have a Tokyo pitch shows that they must have been originally Tokyo-style speakers; they've managed to absorb Kyoto grammar and vocab, but couldn't absorb the pitch.

These observations have inspired Robert Ramsey's [bold theory of the history of Japanese pitch](http://www.jstor.org/stable/132278), which in turn has proved to be quite productive. (The picture above, a translation from Hattori's, is from the linked article.)

Comment: Full disclosure: I'm working on Ramsey's ideas under De Boer; this subfield is still controversial. My senior colleagues have advised me to pay attention to things like rivers and mountain ranges when doing fieldwork, and always ask informants where they grew up; because there were cases where an unexpected pitch pattern was explainable after learning that some guy who "is from here" actually came from across some river.

Answer (score 2):

Some examples for the German language (with links to maps!):

The word [Jause](http://www.atlas-alltagssprache.de/runde-4/f02/) is an Austriacism and is rarely found outside the Austrian
borders.

The word [Broiler](http://www.atlas-alltagssprache.de/9_01b/) still reflects the boundary between Eastern and Western Germany; note also the word Poulet being restricted to Switzerland, Alsace, Lorraine and Luxembourg on the same map.

Also the word [Topfen](http://www.atlas-alltagssprache.de/quark/) is becoming more and more an Austriacism, loosing ground in Bavaria to *Quark*.

Lower level boundaries between different states of Germany can be seen in [this map](http://www.atlas-alltagssprache.de/runde-5/f11a-b/): Different states of Germany use different terminology for written school exams. Here, Bavaria is sticking out.

Comment: thanks, @jknappen, exactly the sort of thing i was looking for and very nice maps to illustrate it! :)

Answer (score 2):

What about looking in to Serbo-Croatian? It was considered one language under Yugoslavia, but now is considered multiple languages. You might like to see:
http://www.economist.com/blogs/economist-explains/2017/04/economist-explains-4
http://www.languagesoftheworld.info/europe/serbo-croatian-tale-two-languages-three-four.html